# android:windowBackground property makes background black (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: image, xamarin.android, background

I want to make the following image to be the background for the entire Xamarin.Android application:

[image]

I reference the image in `Base application theme` in `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    .....
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_app_background_image</item>
    .....
</style>
```

The background applies to all the application but the image has dark background:

[image]

Also the number 51 has some strange things around it.

When I set the `android:background="@drawable/ic_app_background_image"` to the most outer `LinearLayout` of an activity it works fine, it shows the screen like that:

[image]

How can I fix the `android:windowBackground` property setting the background to black issue so I don't have to put `android:background="@drawable/ic_app_background_image"` in the `LinearLayout` of every activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following method:

1.Create new file name as `bg.xml` in `drawable` folder (bg.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

2.define background color in colors.xml

```
   <color name="window_background">#F5F5F5</color>
   <color name="splash_background">#FFFFFF</color>
```

3.define new style `MyTheme.Splash` in `style.xml` and use the `bg` in item `android:windowBackground`

```
 <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```

4.Usage in Activity

```
   [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
     // other code
    }
```

**Update:**

If you want to apply this style to all activities, you can just add the following code to your Base application theme.  And we don't need to set for each activity. For example:

```
  <!-- Base application theme.   parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

The result is:

[image]

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

Comment: Do I have to add `Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash"` above all the activities?

Comment: @Montoolivo    I have updated the answer, you can check it.